# Invalid parameter number PDO, replacing multiple parameters.

Tags: pdo

i'm trying to check multiple columns where their values may contain the search parameter.

```
SELECT * FROM websites 
WHERE county LIKE (:search)
OR dealer_id LIKE (:search)
OR name LIKE (:search)  
OR postcode LIKE (:search)  
OR theme_folder LIKE (:search)  
OR url LIKE (:search)  
OR website_id LIKE (:search)  
OR website_type LIKE (:search)  
LIMIT :start, :end
```

As you can see below i'm binding the parameters:

```
$websites->bindValue(':start', $start, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$websites->bindValue(':end', PAGINATION_WEBSITES_PER_PAGE, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$websites->bindValue(':search', '%'.SEARCH_TERM.'%', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

However i'm getting an error saying:

> Invalid parameter number

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone got any ideas?

Straight from the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.